# Spring controllers extending external abstract class throws classNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, maven, classpath

So I have a spring controller that looks like:

```
@Controller // the org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController extends BaseController {
    ...
}
```

And this works fine. However when I am trying to refactor the code, to move BaseController to an external project "common", the project build will fail with followint stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /mee threw load() exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ca/wherego/common/controllers/BaseController.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
```

I have tried two ways of using the external project:

1) Let maven uses it as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/common-1.0.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

and place the maven in the correct folder ( I don't have a private maven build, so I can't properly upload it as I use other public maven dependencies).

2) I tried to use the "common" project as the project dependency in the build path.

However none of the methods work.. Am I missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: Is the package for BaseController ca.wherego.common.controllers?  If not that could be your problem.

Comment: You have the scope specified as `system`. That means you have to manually supply the jar on the classpath at runtime.

Comment: @chrylis could you please inspire me how to do what? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMadej yes that is where it is located... Eclipse didn't give any error though. Only happening in compilation.

Comment: Yes, don't use `system` scope. It's basically saying "don't do dependency management for this package".

Comment: @jamesdeath123 springdoc says "annotation-based controllers do not have to extend specific base classes or implement specific interfaces". can u explain the reason behind implementing both the things?

Comment: @VipulParalikar They are extending my custom base class because they share some features to process data.